# Angularjs - setting value of list item

Tags: jquery, angularjs

As an Angular newbie I have a simple question...

I can reset the value in an input by using `ng-model="myTextBox"` and then using `$scope.myTextBox = '';` in my controller but how can I reset/clear some text from something that isn't an Angular model such as a list item.

I have:

```
<li my-draggable="#sortable" ng-bind-html="quickLookHtml"></li>
```

and some HTML gets injected into this list item.

**Question:** How can I use Angular to target this list item and clear the value?

Comment: You could use a directive on that li element and then add a function in the directive which clears the content of the `<li>` on a certain event. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You bind the HTML to `$scope.quickLookHtml` so just do `$scope.quickLookHtml = ""`

Comment: I can't believe I didn't try that. Thanks v. much! Will tick when I can.